# Selectively disable log4j debug log in Play console

Tags: scala, playframework, log4j, playframework-2.0, crawler4j

I have a Play 2.0 app, ran `play console` from the command line. Somewhere in one of the libraries I use, it uses `log4j` and started to stream debug output for `[crawler4j][1]`, I'm trying to figure out how to selectively disable that output in the play console. I have tried changing the following in `application.conf` and `logger.xml` without any luck

```
application.conf
logger.root=ERROR
logger.play=ERROR
logger.application=ERROR

logger.xml
<logger name="org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager" level="ERROR"/>
```

Here's a sample of the streaming debug log

```
13:10:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:10:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:10:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:10:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:10:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:10:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:10:18.819 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:11:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:11:18.818 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:11:18.819 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
13:11:18.819 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
```

Just to be clear, the log settings are enforced when I ran the Play app from command line, it's when I run it from within the **`play console`** that the settings are not enforced.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think log4j is in use here actually. Apache HTTP client, which is the library producing the debug, logs via apache commons logging.

Play2 uses the SLF4J API with a logback backend.

There is a library on your classpath called jcl-over-slf4j that causes log messages going to apache commons logging to [bridge through SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and then to logback instead.  (Convoluted I know, but an attempt to allow SLF4J to act as a facade to all the others, and its backend to be the "one logger to rule them all").

The [play2 docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SettingsLogger) indicate logger.xml should allow you to totally customize logging settings, so I think that when there's a logger.xml file present, the application.conf settings have no effect.

logger.xml needs to be a full [logback configuration file](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).  I'm not sure if you've posted the full contents of logger.xml or just the changes.

To suppress output like that shown, you should be able to set the contents of logger.xml to something like this:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm" level="error" />

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

If this doesn't work change the top line to be:

```
<configuration debug="true">
```

which will cause logback to log its attempt to configure itself.  This might give more pointers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, I already did all of that before with no luck. I found that the setting is respected if I ran the Play app from command, problem is when I run it from within Play console, it's not respecting the setting. I'm hoping there is a way to fix that.

Comment: When you run play from within the console with the logback <configuration debug="true"> do you see logback output showing it's initialisation when the app starts?  If not, you could try starting the play console with -Dlogger.resource=conf/logger.xml as a command line option?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, trying it with `-Dlogger.resource=conf/logger.xml` didn't help either. Is `logger.resource` the right variable? Here's the exact command `play -Dlogger.resource=conf/logger.xml console`

Comment: logger.resource is one of the three variables you can use according to the docs.  I'm running low on ideas but one last go.  I'd misunderstood what you meant by console, I thought you meant the play shell, but now I realise you're running the scala console from within that. This might be down to the sbt logger configuration rather than the Play application's.  There is some info about per task loggers at https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks.  I would try: "set logLevel in console := Level.Warn" from the play prompt and then "console". If it works you can add it to your sbt build settings.

Comment: Gallant effort but sadly no go, this is turning out to be quite a pickle. Thanks for your efforts though!

Comment: Play 2.0.3 was released today with a fix for a bug in that _might_ have caused this.  https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/448-play-dist-ignores-loggerxml  Upgrading might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).asInstanceOf[
  ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger].setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO)
```